# Create incremented folders within incremented folders

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file to create folders and sub-folders.

The folders are simply numbered `1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, etc.`

The sub-folders in each folder are `\1100\1101, 1102, 1103, ... \1200\1201, 1202, 1203, etc.`

I have looked at numerous articles both on here and elsewhere.

Most examples refer to pre prepared lists of folder names but as these are incremented numerical folders this doesn't seem the best way to achieve this.

I have the following code:

```
for /l %%x in (1000, 100, 70000) do (
    mkdir %%x 
    cd %%x
    set /a %%y = (%%x + 99)
    for /l %%z in (%%x, 1, %%y) do (
        mkdir %%z
    ) 
    cd ..
)
```

The above code creates nested folders `\1000\1100\1200` before maxing out on file length.

It appears that the variable `%%y` does not pick up its intended value (`%%x + 99`), fails to create the sub-folders in the second for loop, and does not return to the parent before returning to the first for loop.

I am sure there is some mistake in the syntax probably assigning the value to `%%y`, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not in any way attempt to produce the result you have laid out in your question. Additionally, if you open a Command Prompt window and enter `set /?` and `for /?` to read their usage information, you'll learn why your syntax above is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Compo. In what way? I have tried removing the second for loop which works fine (for /l %%x in (1000, 100, 70000) do mkdir %%x). When the second loop is added to create sub-folders they become nested. According to Set /? to assign a value to %%y I need to do Set /a %%y=(%%x + 99) this should give %%y the appropriate value for the maximum value of the sub-folders in the second for loop. I am unable to see where there are issues with the for loops, according to for /? these are correct and should work. Perhaps you would be able to point out which glaring errors you have been able to spot?

Comment: Thanks Compo, I have edited to be more reflective of what I am trying to achieve. I have looked at for /f but it only appears to be able to take a single variable where I need to set both the initial value and final value using variables. I was under the impression that variables in batch files had to be in the format %%variable. I have just tried set /a y=(%%x + 99) and then for /f %%z in (%%x, 1 , %y%) but this still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I think you're trying to achieve:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /L %%A In (1000,100,70000)Do For /L %%B In (1,1,99)Do (
    Set /A Var = %%A + %%B
    MD "%%A\!Var!" 2>NUL)
```